# Database Connection error using sql server and codeigniter in IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, iis, database-permissions

Error to connect MSSQL database through PHP
I can't able to connect to sql server database in remote system. It is showing Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename:

returns the bellow error..

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456
>   [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for
>   user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] =>
>   42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for
>   SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "pestcontrol" requested by
>   the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13
>   for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "pestcontrol"
>   requested by the login. The login failed. ) )

Comment: *"Cannot open database "pestcontrol" requested by the login. The login failed."* ... that's pretty specific, the login failed - which is not hugely surprising since you've not defined a `username` or `password` in `database.php`

Comment: becoz windows authentication only using

Comment: so no need to specify username and pasword right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solve your problem

```
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
```

It is by default setting in xampp, lampp and wampp. If you want create your own credential you can write it in the code given.

or try this link:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/specialhost/how-to-fix-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-iusrs-in-share/

Comment: iis only using windows10

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/specialhost/how-to-fix-login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-iusrs-in-share/  try this solution

Comment: glad to help :)